# Delphi: handling multiple monitors and TForm.Left relative property

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, multiple-monitors

As i show a form i display it where it was last time using `TForm.Left` property i saved on ini file.

I'd like to add support for multiple monitors, because in case of 2 monitors Left can be 2500, so the 2 monitors are seen a a single very wide monitor.

I'd like to save to ini file the monitor number (`TForm.Monitor.MonitorNum`) but to save the relative Left.
Is there a property that tells `Left` according to monitor?

e.g. i have 2 1024x768 monitors, one on the right (main) and one on the left (secondary/extended), if i move a form on the right monitor 2 pixels from the left the `Left` property is 1026. I'd like to say "this is monitor 2 and left is 2".

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no property of TForm that tells its relative position to the monitor it's on. You have to subtract: `Left - Monitor.Left` . In your example that would be 1026 - 1024.

Regardless, I don't see any advantage to this approach compared to storing/setting only the left of the form (i.e. 1026). You can use `MakeFullyVisible` if your concern is monitor arrangement may change between sessions.

Comment: +1 This is sound advice. Just store `Left`. The issue you are concerned about only appears when the user changes layout, but your solution is no good either. What if monitor number 2 has gone? What if there are now 3 monitors? Store `Left` and `Top` and use `MakeFullyVisible`.

Comment: Thanks a lot `MakeFullyVisible` seems the perfect solution, as David Heffernsan says "The issue you are concerned about only appears when the user changes layout" - this is my concern. Thanks a lot.